# Confusing Google icons

Tags: google-account, security, user-interface

This is what I see when an app/script asks to access my Google account:

[image]

There's a circle icon by the sentence "View and.."; and a white arrow icon by the sentence "Display and.."; **What do the icons mean?**

Comment: Just based on the screen shot, I'd say the blue circle is just a bullet, while the icons that look like a page with a folded corner with an arrow are probably links to other pages.

Answer (score -1):

"i inside circle" is just a UI design. If you hover over mouse pointer or click on the icon, it will show all the related information.

This all is to warn the user for secure login or to use any third party app.

Comment: I mean the left icon..

Answer (score -1):

the blue dot icon means: **"this is a common thing for these kinds of stuff/script etc"**

the arrow on a blue sheet means: **"user should pay more attention to these, because it may consist of kinds of things/permissions which user can disagree to provide"**

---

## in short:

- circle = no attention needed
- arrow = could contain sensitive maters